# access to quickpay API provides no right

Tags: c#, vb.net, payment-gateway, payment

I am unfortunately very bad English but I try to do my best for you to understand me.

This is how I have come into a problem like doing that I can not access to Quickpay's API.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            var datoIdag = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            var chars = "123456789";
            var randomA = new Random();
            var result = new string(
            Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 3)
            .Select(s => s[randomA.Next(s.Length)])
            .ToArray());

            var chars2 = "abcdefghijklmno";
            var randomA2 = new Random();
            var result2 = new string(
            Enumerable.Repeat(chars2, 2)
            .Select(s => s[randomA2.Next(s.Length)])
            .ToArray());

            Session["orderId"] = result2 + result + "-" + datoIdag;


            string protocol_value = "1";
            string msgtype_value = "authorize";
            string language_value = "da";
            string autocapture_value = "0";
            string ordernum_value = Session["orderId"].ToString();
            //generate an arbitrary ordernumber
            string merchant_value = "89898978";
            string amount_value = readerPriser["priser"].ToString();
            string qp_currency_value = "DKK";
            //[check available parameters on quickpay.net]
            string okpage_value = "~/PayContinue";
            string errorPage_value = "~/PayCallback";
            string resultpage_value = "~/PayError";
            string md5secret_value = "29p61DveBZ79c3144LW61lVz1qrwk2gfAFCxPyi5sn49m3Y3IRK5M6SN5d8a68u7";
            string md5check_value = GenerateHash(string.Concat(protocol_value.ToString(), msgtype_value, merchant_value, language_value, ordernum_value, amount_value.ToString(), qp_currency_value, okpage_value, errorPage_value, resultpage_value,
            autocapture_value.ToString(), md5secret_value));

            protocol.Value = protocol_value;
            msgtype.Value = msgtype_value;
            language.Value = language_value;
            autocapture.Value = autocapture_value;
            ordernumber.Value = ordernum_value;
            merchant.Value = merchant_value;
            amount.Value = amount_value;
            currency.Value = qp_currency_value;
            continueurl.Value = okpage_value;
            cancelurl.Value = errorPage_value;
            callbackurl.Value = resultpage_value;
            md5check.Value = md5check_value;


    }
}

private string GenerateHash(string Input)
{
    System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Input);
    bs = x.ComputeHash(bs);
    System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in bs) {
        s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
    }
    dynamic outstr = s.ToString();
    return outstr;
}
public _Default()
{
    Load += Page_Load;
}
```

Whenever I try to debug code and see where I fault her, it comes back and tells me this.
http://billedeupload.dk/?v=PWNbK.png

If I write www.blabla.com/PayContinue so it will not appear to be the continue to quickpay api.

If I write the correct address so handelsbetingelserContinue.aspx then it does so it appears with Null. and it does not.

Quickpay have only made it to vb.net, You can see exactly the same file here which I convert from vb.net to c #

```
    Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim protocol_value As Integer = 7
        Dim msgtype_value As String = "authorize"
        Dim language_value As String = "da"
        Dim autocapture_value As Integer = 0
        Dim ordernum_value As String = Now.Ticks 'generate an arbitrary ordernumber
        Dim merchant_value As Integer = 89898978
        Dim amount_value As Integer = 100
        Dim qp_currency_value As String = "DKK" '[check available parameters on quickpay.net]
        Dim okpage_value As String = "http://xprospects.local/continue.aspx"
        Dim errorPage_value As String = "http://xprospects.local/cancel.aspx"
        Dim resultpage_value As String = "http://xprospects.local/callback.aspx"
        Dim md5secret_value As String = "29p61DveBZ79c3144LW61lVz1qrwk2gfAFCxPyi5sn49m3Y3IRK5M6SN5d8a68u7"
        Dim md5check_value As String = GenerateHash(String.Concat(protocol_value.ToString, msgtype_value, merchant_value, language_value, ordernum_value, amount_value.ToString, qp_currency_value, okpage_value, errorPage_value, resultpage_value, autocapture_value.ToString, md5secret_value))

        protocol.Value = protocol_value
        msgtype.Value = msgtype_value
        language.Value = language_value
        autocapture.Value = autocapture_value
        ordernumber.Value = ordernum_value
        merchant.Value = merchant_value
        amount.Value = amount_value
        currency.Value = qp_currency_value
        continueurl.Value = okpage_value
        cancelurl.Value = errorPage_value
        callbackurl.Value = resultpage_value
        md5check.Value = md5check_value

    End Sub

    Private Function GenerateHash(ByVal Input As String) As String
        Dim x As System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider = New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim bs As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Input)
        bs = x.ComputeHash(bs)
        Dim s As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        For Each b As Byte In bs
            s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower())
        Next
        Dim outstr = s.ToString()
        Return outstr
    End Function



End Class
```

Comment: Weird this code should fail at the second ExecuteReader. You don't clear the parameters collection before reusing the same command with a different commandtext

Comment: Posting the error in an image is not correct. Images should only be used when there's no other way to demonstrate the problem. They're difficult for mobile users to see, they're often blocked by corporate proxy servers (meaning they're not available for those readers), and they cost unnecessarily for those users who still pay for data/bandwidth. Please [edit] your question and replace the image with the textual error you're receiving. While you're editing, remove all of the code that isn't relevant to the problem (such as all of the UI and DB related code).

Comment: @KenWhite its good now?

Comment: It's good you removed a lot of the code that wasn't necessary, but the link to the image for the error messages is still there, and the error messages are not. You need to include the *text* of the error messages here. (No picture - words instead.)